# Django Celerybeat PeriodicTask running far more than expected

Tags: django, celery, celeryd, celerybeat, djcelery

I'm struggling with Django, Celery, djcelery & PeriodicTasks.

I've created a task to pull a report for Adsense to generate a live stat report. Here is my task:

```
import datetime
import httplib2
import logging

from apiclient.discovery import build
from celery.task import PeriodicTask
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from oauth2client.django_orm import Storage

from .models import Credential, Revenue


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class GetReportTask(PeriodicTask):
    run_every = datetime.timedelta(minutes=2)

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        scraper = Scraper()
        scraper.get_report()


class Scraper(object):
    TODAY = datetime.date.today()
    YESTERDAY = TODAY - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    def get_report(self, start_date=YESTERDAY, end_date=TODAY):
        logger.info('Scraping Adsense report from {0} to {1}.'.format(
            start_date, end_date))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
        storage = Storage(Credential, 'id', user, 'credential')
        credential = storage.get()
        if not credential is None and credential.invalid is False:
            http = httplib2.Http()
            http = credential.authorize(http)
            service = build('adsense', 'v1.2', http=http)
            reports = service.reports()
            report = reports.generate(
                startDate=start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                endDate=end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                dimension='DATE',
                metric='EARNINGS',
            )
            data = report.execute()
            for row in data['rows']:
                date = row[0]
                revenue = row[1]

                try:
                    record = Revenue.objects.get(date=date)
                except Revenue.DoesNotExist:
                    record = Revenue()
                record.date = date
                record.revenue = revenue
                record.save()
        else:
            logger.error('Invalid Adsense Credentials')
```

I'm using Celery & RabbitMQ. Here are my settings:

```
# Celery/RabbitMQ
BROKER_HOST = "localhost"
BROKER_PORT = 5672
BROKER_USER = "myuser"
BROKER_PASSWORD = "****"
BROKER_VHOST = "myvhost"
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 1
CELERYD_NODES = "w1"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'America/Denver'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'

import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

On first glance everything seems to work, but after turning on the logger and watching it run I have found that it is running the task at least four times in a row - sometimes more. It also seems to be running every minute instead of every two minutes. I've tried changing the run_every to use a crontab but I get the same results.

I'm starting celerybeat using supervisor. Here is the command I use:

```
python manage.py celeryd -B -E -c 1
```

Any ideas as to why its not working as expected?

Oh, and one more thing, after the day changes, it continues to use the date range it first ran with. So as days progress it continues to get stats for the day the task started running - unless I run the task manually at some point then it changes to the date I last ran it manually. Can someone tell me why this happens?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you're not running multiple beat instances at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating a separate queue with one worker process and fixed rate for this type of tasks and just add the tasks in this new queue instead of running them in directly from celerybeat. I hope that could help you to figure out what is wrong with your code, is it problem with celerybeat or your tasks are running longer than expected.

```
@task(queue='create_report', rate_limit='0.5/m')
def create_report():
    scraper = Scraper()
    scraper.get_report()

class GetReportTask(PeriodicTask):
    run_every = datetime.timedelta(minutes=2)

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        create_report.delay()
```

in settings.py

```
   CELERY_ROUTES = {
     'myapp.tasks.create_report': {'queue': 'create_report'},
   }
```

start additional celery worker with that would handle tasks in your queue

celery worker -c 1 -Q create_report -n create_report.local

Problem 2. Your  YESTERDAY and TODAY variables are set at class level, so within one thread  they are set only once.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not exactly sure how to do what you described. Can you give me more details?

Comment: With problem 2, TODAY & YESTERDAY were global variables and I moved them into the class hoping that would help. I have now taken out the variables completely. I'll find out tomorrow if that worked.

Comment: I tried out the code you posted. It solved the problem. It is now running the adsense task once every 2 minutes. I actually have 13 periodic tasks in 8 different apps. Do I have to do a similar thing with each one? They all are running too frequently, but the adsense one was the worst.

Comment: From my experience: when in doubt to have another queue or not to have I always chose separate queue. In your case, i think it would be rather hard to maintain 13+ queues, so make some - one for small tasks and some queues for large tasks, one thing you better not do is run tasks directly from celerybeat, just route them to other queues. Mark my answer as a solution pls.

Comment: So it looks like the real solution was the rate limit. If I remove the rate limit it continuously adds the task. So does the PeriodicTask class even work?

Comment: Your code looks correct, check for recursive calls somewhere in your app. Add sample PeriodicTask which just logs its state to understand if everything is ok with scheduler.

Comment: Odd think happened. After I removed the rate limit on my adsense task, although my adsense queue was adding tasks non-stop, all my other tasks started behaving normally. I then reverted my code to what it was and it is all working as it should now. So frustrating! I have no idea how or why it is fixed all of a sudden.

Comment: This is a good idea to have a rate limit on tasks which are making some kind of RPC calls. If you encounter a strange behavior in your code - you just see extra tasks in this queue and have some time to look for solution, why are they getting there, not breaking everything.